# angularjs delete undefined element in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi everyone i hop you help me in this problem i have 1 array and i want to show it with angularjs in my index.html but it show me my array and undefined element that not exist in array if can any one help me how to delete the undefined element in index.html 
this is the table (js)

```
var tab1 = ["E-Marketing & E-Commerce","Games","Topics","Security","Lunix","Electronics","XBOX","style"]
```

and this is the code angularjs

```
this.selectedContinent;
this.selectedCountry;
this.selectedCity;
tab1.filter(function(i) {
  return i != "b"
});
console.log(tab2);

// this is our dataset
this.continents = [
  {
    'id': 'AM',
    'name': 'arabe',
    'countries': [
      {
        'name': 'ar',
        'cities':tab1
      }
    ]
  }

];
```

and this is the page index.html

```
  Continent:
    <select id="continents" ng-model="ctrl.selectedContinent" ng-options="i.name for i in ctrl.continents">
      <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>

    <br/>

    Country:
    <select id="countries" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" ng-options="i.name for i in ctrl.selectedContinent.countries">
      <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>

    <br/>

    City:
    <select id="cities" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCity" ng-options="i for i in ctrl.selectedCountry.cities"  >
      <option value='' ng-show="ctrl.selectedCity !='undefined'" ></option>
    </select>
```

this is code php

```
<?php

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

include'../db.php';
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),1);

 $getData = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
 $getData->execute();
 $getData2 = $getData->fetchAll();

  if ($getData2) {
// get arabic categories  
    if ($getData2[0]['tra']==1) {

      echo json_encode($getData2);

    } if($getData2[0]['tra']==2){
// get english categories     
      echo json_encode($getData2 = $getData1);
    }

  }else{

    echo "error";

  }
```

this is the controller
all code angularjs

```
app.controller('ControlleArabe',['$scope','Upload','$timeout','$sce','$http','$routeParams','$location',function($scope,Upload,$timeout,$sce,$http,$routeParams,$location){
    $scope.message = "hello word!";
    var tab1 = [];
    var tab2 = [];
            $http({
              method : "GET",
              url : "php/select_ar_categories.php"
              }).then(function (response) {
              $scope.category = response.data;

              for (let index = 0; index < $scope.category.length; index++) {
                 if ($scope.category[index]['tra']==1 && $scope.category[index]['name'] !== 'undefined') {                     
                  $scope.arabe = response.data[index]['name'];
                  tab1[index] = response.data[index]['name'];
                 }else if ($scope.category[index]['tra']==2 && $scope.category[index]['name'] !== 'undefined') {
                  $scope.arabe = response.data[index]['name'];
                  tab2[index] = response.data[index]['name'];

                 }

                }

                $scope.data = {
                  model: null

                 }
             },function(response){

            });

            this.selectedContinent;
            this.selectedCountry;
            this.selectedCity;

            // this is our dataset
            this.continents = [
              {
                'id': 'AM',
                'name': 'arabe',
                'countries': [
                  {
                    'name': 'ar',
                    'cities':tab1
                  },
                  { 
                    'name': 'Canada',
                    'cities':tab2
                  }
                ]
              }

            ];
}]);
```

Comment: where do you have undefined element?

Comment: Please post the controller code of selectedCity, selectedCountry or selectedContinent where you have undefined problem.

Comment: i put my app.js controller thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i find the solution this is it

```
  Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
                      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
                          this.splice(i, 1);
                          i--;
                        }
                      }
                      return this;
                    };
                    tab1.clean(undefined);
                    tab2.clean(undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier solution rather than all that code is to use filter. Assume your array that has the undefined in is this:

```
var tab1 = ["E-Marketing & E-Commerce","Games","Topics","Security","Lunix","Electronics","XBOX","style",undefined];
```

I (ofc) added the undefined. Then use filter to get rid of it:

```
tab1.filter(Boolean);
```

This will result in the array of correct (not undefined) values.